# Are these questions really duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The second of these was marked as a duplicate of the first:

1. [turn list of categorical variables into (0,1) list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40931910/turn-list-of-categorical-variables-into-0-1-list/49149598)
2. [Get ascending order of numbers in array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149374/get-ascending-order-of-numbers-in-array-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have two separate queries and thought it better to ask on Meta rather than chase individual opinions.

**Question 1**

Why are these 2 questions considered exact duplicates? If the same logic were to be applied to the inputs in the respective questions, the outputs will not be aligned with respective desired outputs. It's not a trivial transformation, either, as far as I can see.

**Question 2**

I answered the second question before *I knew* it was marked a duplicate of the first. I posted my answer on the "Exact Duplicate" question. This is bad on two counts. Firstly, the data I'm using has no relation to the duplicate question. Secondly, I believe the questions are different. [I did, however, add comments to explain what I'm doing on both posts.]

Is this good practice? Could I do anything better?

Comment: If you don't think they are duplicates then vote to re-open the question.  That is all it takes.  You'll soon have a gold badge and then it just takes a single vote.  Use the power wisely.

Comment: @HansPassant, if I were to vote to reopen, would I get a notification if/when it is reopened? otherwise, it's likely to be lost (for all purposes).

Comment: You can favorite the question.

Comment: There is no notification.  No reason for it to be "lost", users can post an answer again.  It would be wise for the OP to edit it so it gets reactivated.  What we always expect askers to do when their question is put on hold.  If it has to be you to post that answer then click the star on the question so you can keep track of it.  If you have no faith in the process then just ask the question yourself, self-answered Q+A is quite acceptable.

Comment: OK, this seems fine to me. I will wait a few more hours in case there are other opinions, otherwise will delete this question.

Comment: ... It's weird. I don't think it's a duplicate. @Divakar? (I know the ping doesn't work) (I upvoted the meta question, too)

Comment: @HansPassant: It looks like jpp (probably) did that, but [the reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/19032815) ended with one "Reopen" vote to three "Leave Closed". I'm starting to suspect that reopen review is simply not working, given that even obvious non-dupes like this IME almost always fail to get reopened. In this case, of course, the question might still get reopened anyway due to the meta effect.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, to confirm: I did vote to reopen.

Comment: The question is certainly open now, so here's your notification @jpp

Comment: @MichaelGaskill, have to reclose now since an answer was updated to make it a duplicate !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those are definitely not the same question.  I don't know what the close voter was thinking.  Maybe they just had a momentary brain fart or something.

In principle, the thing to do in such cases is simply to vote to reopen the question.  Unfortunately, this sends it into the reopen review queue, where IME the success rate for even "obviously" mistaken closures like this one seems pretty close to negligible.*  And if the review task gets completed as "Leave Closed" ([as seems to have happened in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/19032815)), the odds are pretty low that anyone else would just randomly stumble across the question and vote to reopen it before your vote times out.

In practice, more effective ways to get a mistakenly closed question reopened include:

- Posting about the situation on meta, like you did here.  This will attract lots of extra eyeballs to the question, and if it's really not a duplicate, there's a decent chance that it will get reopened.
- Asking for help on chat, e.g. in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room.  Some of the folks there can have a pretty high bar for question quality, but if you can clearly and succintly argue why the closure was inappropriate, it can be an effective way to get the necessary number of votes in.
- In cases like this, where the question was closed by a single gold badge holder or a moderator, you can [@ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) the closing user in a comment and let them know you think the closure was mistaken.  (Yes, this works even if their username doesn't appear in the tab completion list.)  If they agree, they can also reopen the question singlehandedly.
- Finally, while I'm a bit hesitant to suggest this as a general course of action, I should note for the sake of completeness that I've had some degree of success in the past with politely worded custom moderator flags.  Given that the ♦ mods have quite a lot of work on their hands, however, you really shouldn't do this unless you've already tried other, more standard methods first, and really believe that the situation is not easily resolvable by the ordinary community-based moderation mechanisms.

---

*) In my admittedly limited and anecdotal experience, the major problem with the reopen review queue seems to be that it's flooded with huge numbers of [autoflagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078) questions that have absolutely no reason to ever be reopened.  As a result, many reviewers there tend to get into the habit of automatically clicking "Leave Closed" unless the question is *obviously* of *very high* quality (which usually means that it's an audit).

As an illustration of the low success/decline rate in the reopen review queue, [this SEDE query I made](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/794676/reopen-review-outcome-statistics-excluding-most-audits#graph) shows that 331 questions have been successfully reopened via review since the beginning of this year, while 4,445 reopen reviews have ended with the question being left closed.  That's less than one in 14 completed reviews resulting in the question actually being reopened.

(During the same time period, 393 reopen reviews were invalidated as inconclusive for some reason, presumably e.g. because the question was deleted while it was under review or was reopened by a gold badge holder from outside review.  These numbers *should* exclude most audits, although filtering those out on SEDE is kind of tricky, [as I've discussed here on meta.SE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306378/how-to-distinguish-audits-from-real-reviews-in-sede-data/306399#306399))

Comment: I would add an option to just vote for reopening *along with* a comment. When I review reopen votes I tend to read the last comments.